# How can one test a design post development

Tags: website-design, testing

I am trying to find out if there is way to test an app design post development , if the development is implemented pixel perfect as per the design specs or not.

Is there a tool that would help testing the above.

Comment: Do you mean user testing? If the app is developed you can conduct any multitude of user tests. What do you need to know? Are you wanting to validate the visual design aspect of the app?

Comment: Yes, I want to know to about visual aspect of the app, post development. Tester do check the  design comparing to the design provided, but still I am not sure that the developers are matching pixel to pixel with given design. I am trying to figure out if there is any tool to so.

Answer (score 2):

This is borderline off-topic, but I'm answering because it's not purely about implementation. It's question about testing designs.

You can easily test pixel perfection using the **Firefox add-in called 'Pixel Perfect'**, which lets you overlay the design spec over the live page. Useful for testing and development. Of course, this will only work for static elements like layout and typography, not interactions or animations.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/pixel-perfect/